# Es posible automatizar Gradle para que me ejecute diferentes configuraciones de DB sabiendo que tengo un Java Hibérnate

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

Tengo un proyecto el cual trabaja con varias bases de datos (Ambientes) estos todos funcionan, pero lo que querria realizar es: varias Task desde gradle las cuales automaticen las configuraciones de DB.

Para los diferentes ambientes con sus respectivas base de datos, porque por el momento el funcionamiento es comentar y descomentar configuración.

Comment: La idea tuya es que exista sólo una configuración de base "descomentada" en todo momento? Siendo ese el caso podrías implementar perfiles de arranque. De esta manera podrías por medio de variables de entorno cargar uno u otro perfil (archivo json, xml, yaml, properties... con la configuración del ambiente) en la ejecución de tu programa